# When using resolution variable elimination to simplify a cnf, does that change the truth values of the other variables?

Tags: satisfiability, boolean-algebra

When you use resolution [variable elimination](https://www.msoos.org/2014/04/why-its-hard-to-eliminate-variables/) to preprocess/simplify a formula in cnf form the resulting formula is equisatisfiable.

What I wonder about is if I can use this technique to remove variables i don't care about while leaving the truth values of the variables I care about untouched in the final model I get from the sat solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Any satisfying assignment for the simplified formula can be extended to a satisfying assignment for the original formula, by setting appropriate values to the eliminated variables (but not changing the values of the remaining variables), and vice versa.